# ocaml define type and use it for calculation

Tags: types, ocaml

I have the following type value, and  I want to do a calculation base on those type but I got a error saying that:

> This expression has type value but an expression was expected of type int

So what should I do to do calculation?

```
type binop = 
  | Plus 
  | Minus 
  | Mul 
  | Div 
  | Eq 
  | Ne 
  | Lt 
  | Le 
  | And 
  | Or          
  | Cons

type expr =   
  | Const of int 
  | True   
  | False      
  | NilExpr
  | Var of string    
  | Bin of expr * binop * expr 
  | If  of expr * expr * expr
  | Let of string * expr * expr 
  | App of expr * expr 
  | Fun of string * expr    
  | Letrec of string * expr * expr

type value =  
  | Int of int      
  | Bool of bool          
  | Closure of env * string option * string * expr 
  | Nil                    
  | Pair of value * value 

val x : value = Int 1
val x : value = Int 1
```

when I do this

```
 x+x;;
```

then it throws that errors, and I want something like this:

```
 Nano.value = Int 2
```

fix something like this it will return `value = Int` something but I want the `Nano.value = Int` something, and the file called Nano.ml so I want the `Nano.value`

```
let add (x,y) = match (x,y) with 
   | (Int xx, Int yy) -> Int (xx + yy)
   | ( _ , _) -> Int 0
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no '+' operator defined for values of type value, so what's happening here is that you're calling the '+' operator for integers.

You would need to define an operator for adding your value types:

```
let ( +! ) x y = match (x,y) with 
   | (Int xx, Int yy) -> xx + yy
   |  _ -> raise <some exception>

Int 8 +! Int 2  ... should yield 10.
```

(Note: I don't have easy access to an OCaml REPL right now, so that may not compile)

Also, not sure what adding two Closures, Nil's or Pair's would mean, you'd have to determine that for your addition operator, you'll notice that I just raise some exception for anything but Ints.  You would want to fill in the actions appropriate for the type.

Comment: No, + has type : `int -> int -> int`; you should define your own addition operator for your type as in, `value -> value -> value`.

Comment: i wrote something like this.  above in the fix area . but it return a value = Int 10;  but i want something like Nano.value = Int 10;

Comment: The REPL is not going to print `Nano` out if the module is open. They are functionally the same output. Why so fastidious?

Comment: `Nano.value` within the `Nano` module is just printed by the REPL as  `value`.

Comment: Don't open the Nano module? When I just do `#load "nano.cmo" I get the behavior you say you want. (As nlucaroni wisely points out, it doesn't pay to be too choosy about the way the top-level works. You should work *with* it rather than *against* it.)

Comment: Yeah, I wrongly assumed it was because of #load or an open command on the module. I guess `#use` would do it though.

Comment: i dont really understand what you guys talking about = =

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer mentions, you need to define your own "plus" operator for the `value` type.  Something like this should work:

```
exception Bad_addition

let rec (++) a b = match (a,b) with
  | (Int(x),Int(y)) -> Int(x+y)
  | (Bool(x),Bool(y)) -> Bool(x || y)
  | (Nil,Nil) -> Nil
  | (Pair(x1,y1),Pair(x2,y2)) -> Pair(x1 ++ x2,y1 ++ y2)
  | _ -> raise Bad_addition
```

That will give you an operator called `++` which you can then use to add values together.  For example, doing `Int(1) ++ Int(1)` produces the result `Int(2)`.

Note that I have defined the "addition" of booleans to be the logical or, addition of two `Nil` values to be `Nil`, and addition of pairs to be pointwise addition, but you may with to implement different behavior for these.